# Getting pairs of siblings from div in scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a timeline and need if class isn't active to change css for each pair that is moved from active year. This is the case.

```
...
n-4
n-3
n-2
n-1
n (active year)
n+1
n+2
n+3
n+4
...
```

This is what I tried but that goes by index

```
  $frame.sly(`on`, `active`, function (event) {
 $(`.years.active`).css(`opacity`,`1`);
 $(`.years.active`).siblings().eq(1).css(`opacity`,0.9`);
 $(`.years.active`).siblings().eq(2).css(`opacity`,`0.8`);
 $(`.years.active`).siblings().eq(3).css(`opacity`,`0.7`);
 $(`.years.active`).siblings().eq(4).css(`opacity`,`0.6`);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="pagespan container">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="frame" id="forcecentered">
            <ul class="clearfix">
                <li data-target="1997" class="years">1997</li>
                <li data-target="2009" class="years">2009</li>
                <li data-target="2010" class="years">2010</li>
                <li data-target="2013" class="years active">2013</li>
                <li data-target="2015" class="years">2015</li>
                <li data-target="2016" class="years">2016</li>
                <li data-target="2017" class="years">2017</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyone knows the way that this could be done. Maybe with data target?
I want to achive so that each step from active li the font and opacity is smaller

Comment: Please show the HTML and explain what you are looking to do more clearly.

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: ... And the CSS... All the relevant code. And, please clarify what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: I did gave the relevant code. There isn't anymore all styling is are those inline styles. Only that javascript when you do scroll another class is given active(it's sly plugin). and I want to repeat the proces

Comment: You have CSS class references, not inline styles. Where are those classes? **And, you still haven't edited your question to make it clear what it is you want to do.**

Comment: that is just something I can grab on to when using javascript. Only "active" class is given by sly slider

Comment: CSS should be used for styling, not for a JavaScript hook. You should use HTML `data-*` attributes for that. And, what does *"change css for each pair that is moved from active year"* mean? Each "pair" of what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an attribute to keep track of the levels:

```
function moveForward() {
    $(“.before”).each(function() {
        $(this).attr(“data-pos”, $(this).attr(“data-pos”) + 1);
    }
    $(“.after”).each(function() {
        $(this).attr(“data-pos”, $(this).attr(“data-pos”) - 1);
    }
    $(“.active”).toggleClass(“active before”).attr(“data-pos”, 1);
    $(“.after[data-pos=‘0’]”).toggleClass(“after active”);
}

function moveBack() {
    $(“.before”).each(function() {
        $(this).attr(“data-pos”, $(this).attr(“data-pos”) - 1);
    }
    $(“.after”).each(function() {
        $(this).attr(“data-pos”, $(this).attr(“data-pos”) + 1);
    }
    $(“.active”).toggleClass(“active after”).attr(“data-pos”, 1);
    $(“.before[data-pos=‘0’]”).toggleClass(“before active”);
}
```

Of course you can call these multiple times (or modify them) to change by multiple entries, and track the position in a variable to allow for a “go to position” function.

And then your css:

```
/* any pos greater than 9 */
.before, .after {
    opacity: 0;
}

/* these selectors should be sufficient because ‘.active’ will always have no ‘data-pos’ or will have a ‘data-pos’ of 0 */
[data-pos=‘1’] {
    opacity: 0.9;
}

[data-pos=‘2’] {
    opacity: 0.8;
}
/* values 3-9 here */
```

And make sure your html is pre-set correctly, e.g.

```
<div class=“before” data-pos=“2”/>
<div class=“before” data-pos=“1”/>
<div class=“active”/>
<div class=“after” data-pos=“1”/>
<div class=“after” data-pos=“2”/>
<div class=“after” data-pos=“3”/>
<div class=“after” data-pos=“4”/>
```

Comment: this is it, Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to decrease the opacity of **LI**s from the active one to the end. If this is the case the snippet is:

```js
var elements = $('.years.active').nextAll('.years').andSelf();
var step = 1 / (1 + elements.length);
var startValue = 1;
elements.each(function(idx, ele) {
    startValue = startValue - 0.1;
    console.log('New opacity is (li:' + ele.textContent + '):' + startValue);
    $(ele).css('opacity',startValue);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="pagespan container">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="frame" id="forcecentered">
            <ul class="clearfix">
                <li data-target="1997" class="years">1997</li>
                <li data-target="2009" class="years">2009</li>
                <li data-target="2010" class="years">2010</li>
                <li data-target="2013" class="years active">2013</li>
                <li data-target="2015" class="years">2015</li>
                <li data-target="2016" class="years">2016</li>
                <li data-target="2017" class="years">2017</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes like that but the problem is I want to start from the middle

Comment: sorry... I'm rushing, by middle I ment 2013(or 4 element)

Comment: @OunknownO Snippet updated. Like you can see I start from 2013. Let me know.